# How to parse then paste in an other file

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file like this `A.txt` (field separator = `;`) :

```
kit;;;;;;;
Software Version = cti;;;;;;;
Date And Time of Export = 06/02/20  14:14:11;;;;;;;
Experiment Name = taqpath-AB17500-plate7587;;;;;;;
Instrument Software Version = ;;;;;;;
Instrument Type = sds7500fast;;;;;;;
Instrument Serial Number = ;;;;;;;
Run Start Date = Tue Jun 02 12:00:40 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run End Date = Tue Jun 02 13:14:42 CEST 2020;;;;;;;
Run Operator = FE;;;;;;;
Batch Status = VALID;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
```

And `B.csv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
Well    Cycle   Target Name Rn  ΔRn Sample Name 
A1  1   N gene  512629.375  1004.0445   B1000-1 
A1  2   N gene  515089.2188 2157.2146   B1000-1 
A1  3   N gene  514001.7812 -236.8966   B1000-1
```

And I want to parse the 4th line of `A.txt` and paste some infos in the last column of `B.csv` like this :

```
Well    Cycle   Target Name Rn  ΔRn Sample Name Plate Name
A1  1   N gene  512629.375  1004.0445   B1000-1 plate7587
A1  2   N gene  515089.2188 2157.2146   B1000-1 plate7587
A1  3   N gene  514001.7812 -236.8966   B1000-1 plate7587
```

I try something like for the parsing part (and it works) but I don't know how to paste it in the last column of `B.txt` and add "Plate Name" as header:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=" = "} NR==4{split($2,a,"-")}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the A.txt has only one experiment name , you could do this :

```
$ awk -F";" '/Experiment Name/{ split($1,a,"-"); } NR>FNR{ if(FNR==1) print $0" Plate name"; else print $0" "a[3] }' A.txt B.csv  > tmp && mv tmp B.csv
Well    Cycle   Target Name Rn  ΔRn Sample Name  Plate name
A1  1   N gene  512629.375  1004.0445   B1000-1  plate7587
A1  2   N gene  515089.2188 2157.2146   B1000-1  plate7587
A1  3   N gene  514001.7812 -236.8966   B1000-1 plate7587
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v1=`awk 'NR==4{print $0}' p3| awk -F "-" '{gsub(";","",$3);print $3}'`

 awk -v v1="$v1" 'BEGIN{print "Well Cycle Target Name Rn ΔRn Sample Plate Name"}NR>1{$NF=v1;print }' p4
```

output

```
Well Cycle Target Name Rn ΔRn Sample Plate Name
A1 1 N gene 512629.375 1004.0445 plate7587
A1 2 N gene 515089.2188 2157.2146 plate7587
A1 3 N gene 514001.7812 -236.8966 plate7587
```